# Present viewcontroller with tabbar

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I created UITabBarController programmatically in AppDelegate with 4 view controllers(using .xib). When user tap some button on ViewController (VC-A) it present another VC (VC-B) and covered tabbar.  So I want to VC-B has a tabbar on the button.

I tried to add VC-B as a child of tabbarcontroller. I tried to .present(vc) and .show(vc) on both: VC-A and VC-A.TabBarController

Creating controllers in AppDelegate:

```
 let controllers = [tabViewController1,tabViewController2,tabViewController3,tabViewController4]
 tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
 window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

presenting in VC-A

```
self.tabBarController?.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You are confused about how `present` actually works. It literally presents a VC on top of the current VC. So it covers all the screen and your tabBar won’t be visible. If you want to keep the tabBar, embed the tabBarController in a navigationController and use `push` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to embed every VC in navigationController and then add to TabBarController.

```
let vc1 = ViewController1()

let navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
navController.isNavigationBarHidden = true

let controllers = [navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4]
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers 

window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Then call

> self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated:
>   true)

To diplay VC with tabbar

Answer (score 0):

right click and drag from tabbar controller in storyboard to VC-B. that should create a tab on the bottom of your VC-A and VC-B to go back and forth without having to implement any backend code unless you want to animate

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I will press the red login button at the bottom of the picture and try to log in.
login button => "로그인"

After that, log in.

```
let moreVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoreViewController") as! MoreViewController

                moreVC.definesPresentationContext = true
                moreVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: moreVC)

                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If the login proceeds without error, the above code will be called to display the screen when the login is completed.

If the flow proceeds as the code above, this screen appears.

[image]

The screen shown is not fullscreen, and the tabbar at the bottom is gone. The screen I want is the screen below.

[image]

How can I present a tab bar when presenting the screen?

Comment: I also have same question ... but you just ask the question in the answer section ...